# Include computername parameter with Get-WmiObject data

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I want to include the computer name with some of the returned data of the WMI query.  I've studied custom columns - need something like that - but I do not know how to pass the computer name into the next loop to be included in the resulting table.  For example:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName MailServer01
```

Actually, I'm in another look where `$_` is the computer name:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_
```

This works great, but I want to include the `ComputerName` `($_)` as part of the final output or report.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The computername is already there (as SystemName).  It just isn't part of the default display properties.

Run

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName MailServer01 | format-list *
```

to see all of the properties of the returned objects.

Comment: Huh, didn't know that was there. Better answer than mine, fewer commands to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The "__Server" property will always be available for the get-wmiobject objects

Also note:

"Beginning in Windows PowerShell 3.0, the __Server property of the object that Get-WmiObject returns has a PSComputerName alias. This makes it easier to include the source computer name in output and reports."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Get-WMiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $_ -PassThru
```

Then you can output or manipulate your data anyway you see fit, and the properties you add via `Add-Member` will be available on that object as long as it exists.

Docs for the cmdlet are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849879.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I didn't realize there were more properties.  Works great: __Server was the property I needed:

```
  $myServers = @("server1", "server2", "server3")

  "" > space.txt

  $myServers | foreach-object { 
     write-host "Server: $_"
     Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $_ | ? { $_.DeviceID -notmatch "  [AR]"} | Select -Property __Server, DeviceID, @{Name=’FreeSpaceMB’;Expression={$_.FreeSpace/1MB} } | Format-Table -AutoSize  >> c:\space.txt

  }
```